# Should method be always virtual when derived?

Tags: c++

The title says it all (I am not sure when to use `virtual` keyword). Should function `SaySomething()` be `virtual` in this case? (or maybe it only should be `virtual` when using pointers?)

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
    public:
        void SaySomething(){
            std::cout << "aaaaaa";
        }
};

class B : public A{
    public:
        void SaySomething(){
            std::cout << "bbbbbbb";
        }
};

int main(){
    A objectA;
    B objectB;

    objectA.SaySomething();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    objectB.SaySomething();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically there is no need for the function `B::SaySomething` to be `virtual` in this case: the compiler knows the run-time type of each object, so it will call the proper method in both cases.

However, the fact that it has the same name as `A::SaySomething` from the base class but does *not* override it may mislead the readers of your code. If you plan to hide, rather than to override `A::SaySomething` in class `B`, then the best practice is to give the member function a different name.

Here is a situation when it matters:

```
B b;
A &ab(b);
b.SaySomething();  // Calls B::SaySomething
ab.SaySomething(); // Calls A::SaySomething
```

The behavior when changing the way through which you reference the same object changes the behavior of a method is not what readers of your code expect. If you make `A::SaySomething` virtual, both calls would produce the same behavior.

Comment: So from what I understand "It is good practice to make function SaySomething() virtual in this case even if technically there is no difference" is it right?

Comment: @user3609825 It all depends on your intent. If you expect derived classes to have a function with the same name and parameters, make it virtual. Otherwise, keep the function non-virtual, and avoid functions with the same name in the derived class. So there are two ways of making your code easier to understand: (1) make `A::SaySomething` virtual, or (2) rename `B::SaySomething` to avoid the naming confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
class A {
    virtual void f() { cout << 1 << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
    virtual void f() { cout << 2 << endl; }
};
```

then when you use it in code like this:

```
A* a = new B();
a->f();
```

your program will write 2 because you used `virtual`. It dynamically resolves that the pointed object is of type B, although pointer is of type A.

If you don't use `virtual` it would print 1 and use the function from pointer type class.

Answer (score 0):

The `virtual` keyword is what enables [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) in C++.  Your example is strictly non-polymorphic since the method call resolution is static.  So it's not necessary in your example.

However, if you had...

```
class Shape {

  virtual double area() = 0;
}

class Circle : public Shape {

  virtual double area() {
    return PI * r * r;
  }
}

class Square : public Shape {

  virtual double area() {
    return h * w;
  }
}
```

The code...

```
Shape* shapes[2];

shapes[0] = new Circle(1);
shapes[1] = new Square(1, 1);

for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    cout << "shape[" << i << "] area -> " << shapes[i]->area();
```

would print the area for both the circle, and the square...

```
shape[0] area -> 3.1415926..
shape[1] area -> 1
```